# Delete all numbered version of a specific language version using c#

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-api

I have to delete the language version of a Sitecore item. For Ex. if it has 5 numbered versions in the English language so I have to delete all 5 at once.

I have tried by `item.Versions.RemoveVersion()`; but it deletes only one numbered version. Is there any other method available for this?

Comment: Have you tried item.Versions.RemoveAll()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `item.Versions.RemoveAll()` method.

```
Language languageRemove = Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse(languageCode);
Item rootItem = db.GetItem(rootItemPath, languageRemove);
if (rootItem != null)
{
    using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
    {
        //Remove all the versions from item
        rootItem.Versions.RemoveAll(false);
    }
}
```